# Macro Do Until Loop Copy from list of values paste into single cell (e.g. b1)

Tags: vba, excel, macros

This is my first post here, so that you in advance for your help. What a great community!

I am trying to write a macro that will loop through a list of values of an undetermined number of rows and one by one copy and paste the values into a single cell, each time through loop replacing the value that was just pasted into the single cell, which is referenced by a report template and auto-populates data based on the id of the number

Here is an example of what the table will look like:

```
__|__A__|__B__
1 | 231 | 234
2 | 232 |
3 | 233 |
4 | 234 |
5 | 235 |
6 | 236 |
```

231 would be copied and pasted into B1, then 232 would be copied and pasted into B1, then 233 would be copied and pasted into B1, then 234 would be copied and pasted into B1.....and so on and so forth. In between the copy and past steps there are other steps to add images to a worksheet and save as a pdf.

I wrote this script to accomplish the goal:

```
Sub Report()
'
' Report Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+G
'
' this section just copies a selection of cells from on worksheet and moves it to another worksheet filters it and copies filtered list to yet another worksheet.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Master Sheet").Select
Range("A6").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$BS$410").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="2"
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Report").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
' This section does the operation outlined at beginning of post.
Range("A1").Select
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!ErasePhoto"
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!PhotoPlace"
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ChDir "C:"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Range("B3").Value          _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True,  IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!ErasePhoto"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
End Sub
```

When I run the macro it goes through once successfully, but doesn't loop. I'm not sure why? Thanks!!!!

Comment: Thanks Dirk for fixing the formatting, I'm new to this, so all the help I can get is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Step through the code to see what cells are the active cells when the loop is executed? The code sets B1 as the active cell in each loop. Without knowing what the called procedures do, it's hard to tell what cell is affected with `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select` before the Loop.

The code has a lot of unnecessary selects and activate statements. Clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I was able to find the answer on an excel forum from a wonderfully kind person named skywriter. It worked like a charm.

```
Dim r As Range 
For Each r In Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 
    Range("B1").Value = r.Value 
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!ErasePhoto" 
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!PhotoPlace" 
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1 
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 
    ChDir "C:" 
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF,       Filename:=Range("B3").Value _ 
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _ 
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True 
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!ErasePhoto" 
Next r
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a minor change in your code by adding a `counter` variable which is then used in the `Do Until` loop. This lets you select the desired cell using `Offset`.

```
' This section does the operation outlined at beginning of post.
Range("A1").Select
Dim counter As Long    '---->line added
counter = 1            '---->line added
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!ErasePhoto"
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!PhotoPlace"
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ChDir "C:"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Range("B3").Value _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!ErasePhoto"
    ActiveCell.Offset(counter, -1).Select    '----> make change here
    counter = counter + 1                    '----> line added
Loop
```